# How to parse the attached JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

The following is  valid. How do I access the data using `JSON.parse`.

```
[
    {
        "node_title": "MGP",
        "nid": "4",
        "Album": "Myalbum1",
        "Artist": "Myartist"
    },
    {
        "node_title": "PW",
        "nid": "3",
        "Album": "Myalbum1",
        "Artist": "Myartist"
    }
]
```

Comment: The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON, optionally transforming the value produced by parsing. How you can retrieve it using this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This

```
var jsonString= '[
  {"node_title": "MGP", "nid": "4", "Album": "Myalbum1", "Artist": "Myartist"},
  {"node_title": "PW", "nid": "3", "Album": "Myalbum1", "Artist": "Myartist"}
]'

    var jsonFormatVariable = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString); // in jquery library parse;
 var jsonFormatVariable = JSON.parse(jsonString); // in native js  parse;

console.log(jsonFormatVariable );
```

Comment: How can we do it in Javascript? Please provide example, say for instance if I need to access node_title from the two objects.

Comment: For Native javascript change `jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);` to `JSON.parse(jsonString)`

Comment: After the JSON.parse can I access node_title in relation to jsonFormatVariable? Please give example. jsonFormatVariable[0].node_title does not work.

Comment: See In this `http://jsfiddle.net/w2epq1qr/`